# Building a local testing environment using Minikube and AWS ECS

Tags: kubernetes, dns, amazon-ecs, minikube

I am building a local testing environment using `Kubernetes Minikube` cluster. "Some" of the backend APIs and the database were deployed inside the cluster and each of these APIs has its dedicated URL created using `ingress`. In addition to that, I've deployed "all" the backend APIS in `AWS ECS`, each of these APIs has a `Route53` record, and the frontend is connected to these APIs in the ".env" file. What I want to achieve is, when I run `yarn start` on my frontend(React) outside of the cluster, the frontend should first check if the service is presented in the local `Minikube` cluster, if it can't find the service in the cluster, it will connect to the one in `AWS ECS`. Is there a way to achieve this?

For better illustration, this is my frontend `.env` file

```
SCHEDULE_API_URL = http://schedule.learning.com
DASHBOARD_API_URL = http://dashboard.learning.com
```

backend deployment yaml

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: schedule
  labels:
    name: schedule
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: schedule
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: schedule
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: schedule
        image: <image_name>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        imagePullPolicy: Never
      restartPolicy: Always
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: schedule-svc
  labels:
    app: schedule
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: schedule-ingress
 namespace: default
 annotations:
   kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "12h"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
 rules:
   - host: schedule.learning.com
     http:
       paths:
         - path: /
           pathType: Prefix
           backend:
             service:
               name: schedule-svc
               port:
                 number: 80
```

Backend APIs that have been deployed in AWS ECS

```
SCHEDULE API  --> Route 53 Record: http://schedule.learning.com
DASHBOARD API  --> Route 53 Record: http://dashboard.learning.com
```

Based on the above example, when I run the frontend locally and outside of the cluster, it will connect to the `Schedule API`
http://schedule.learning.com in the local cluster, but connect to the dashboard API https://dashboard.learning.com in ECS since it couldn't find it in the cluster.

Note:

- The frontend is deployed outside of the cluster
- The API in the `local` cluster will have the same URL as the `ECS` one so that the frontend `env` doesn't have to be modified.
- Even the  `Minikube` cluster is deployed locally, it is still a virtual machine

Comment: It looks like you've asked almost the same question in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65859804/split-horizon-dns-in-local-minikube-cluster-and-aws) Does that solution solved your issue or this question is different?

Comment: The question is slightly different. In this question the frontend is deployed outside of the cluster, which is more convenient for the developers to do local testing. So the communication will no longer be within the cluster, but 1. the frontend outside and the cluster, 2. the frontend and the AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think more versatile solution would be if you would have [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) with two hosts solution. This way you wouldn't need any infrastructure changes (only a few adjustments in names).

In this solution, you would need to:

- Enable `Ingress` in `Minikube` using `$ minikube addons enable ingress`
- Create `LoadBalancer` to service on cloud environment
- Have 2 deployments in Cloud environment and Minikube.
- Add to `/etc/hosts` aliases for `$ minikube ip` address like

```
192.168.49.2 resource1.domain1.biz
192.168.49.2 resource2.domain2.biz
```

- Have 2 services, one which pointing to deployment in Minikube, second should be without `selector`.
- Create `Endpoint` for second service pointing to `LoadBalancer` IP.

**Configs**

***Ingress***

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: resource1.domain1.biz
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /first
        backend:
          serviceName: first-deployment
          servicePort: 8080
  - host: resource2.domain2.biz
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /second
        backend:
          serviceName: my-svc
          servicePort: 8080
```

***Endpoint***

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: my-svc
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 34.91.XX.27 
    ports:
      - port: 80
```

**Tests***

```
user@minikube-20:~$ curl -H "HOST: resource1.domain1.biz" http://192.168.49.2/first
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: first-deployment-5df6dc8d8b-mmx8c
user@minikube-20:~$ curl -H "HOST: resource2.domain2.biz" http://192.168.49.2/second
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: gke-deployment-85b75bf4f9-jgvhz
```

In this scenario you could also try to use [ExternalName service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname)

However, if you would like to achieve what you mention originally, which is creating `automatic failover` you would need to interference your configuration.

You could use:

- `CoreDNS plugin` called [Alternate](https://github.com/coredns/alternate)

> Plugin Alternate is able to selectively forward the query to another upstream server, depending the error result provided by the initial resolver

- Some kind of `LoadBalancer` or `proxy` with `health-check` and request retry like in [this example](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-health-check/)

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I am looking for! A side question, is there any other better way/practice that has been generally adopted to create a local testing environment for a large scale app like this one?